# lxappearance, FreeBSD and normal user

Tags: freebsd, desktop-environment, openbox, gtk, icons

I set pure Openbox desktop on FreeBSD 10 and I am usingn `lxappearance` for theme, font and icon changes.
but if i do `$ > lxappearance` I can't install icon themes or GTK+ themes. if i do `$ > sudo lxappearance` and install icons or themes; those themes would not be in lxappearance list when i run `lxappearance` without `sudo`.
if i select a theme by `$ > sudo lxappearance` whether GTK+ or Icon theme, thoes themes would only applies to root not my account.

PS: i have a solution and that's putting the icons and gtk+ in a folder that is in `~` my home directory. but i don't know what would be the path and if they would be picked up by `lxappearance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System-wide:**

`/usr/local/share/themes` # for GTK+ 2&3
`/usr/local/share/icons`  # for ICON Sets

**User-specific**
`~/.icons`
`~/.themes`
`~/.conf/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`  #for gtk3 config
`~/gtkrc-2.0` #for gtk-2 config